# How can I track visitors’ paths from one page to another with full URLs?

Tags: google-analytics

Say I have two pages on a site called “Page 1” and “Page 10”. I'd like to be able to see the paths visitors take to get from “Page 1” to “Page 10” with full URLs intact. Many of the URLs (including those for “Page 1” and “Page 10”) will include query strings that are important.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using **[behavior flow reports](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2785577)**. The report basically shows you how visitors click through your website. There are a lot of ways to [customize](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2519989) the report, with which you will need to play around to really answer your question. By default, the behavior flow focuses on entry and exit points of visitors, regardless how many times they hit the different subpages in between. However, I'm sure you can set appropriate filters and settings to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I use two methods for tracking where people have been on my website:

1. Track and store the information in my own SQL database. (details below)
2. [Lead Forensics](http://leadforensics.com/) (paid subscription, but you can do a trial).

For tracking and storing my own data, I record unique visitors based upon the IP Address they're connecting from and then have a separate table that records all page views that links back to the unique visitor table.

Lead Forensics data simply allows me to link up those unique visitors with actual companies that have viewed my website.

Doing it yourself means you don't have to rely on Google working for your records to work, and in my experience Google Analytics tends to round numbers so you don't get a true indication of numbers, and also you can remove bots and website trawlers from your data by tracking the user agent string.

Answer (score 0):

As a somewhat ugly hack you could use transaction tracking. If you use the same transaction id multiple times subsequent products will be added to the existing data. So assign an ID at the start of the visits and on each page record a transaction with the current page url as product name (and the ID as transaction id). This will give you the complete path per user (I am frankly not to sure how this is useful - at some point you probably want aggregated data. Plus each transaction and product counts towards your quota for interaction counts, so on a large site you might run over the 10mio hits limit).

Answer (score 0):

you can do it programatically

- have a MAP in the backend which stores the userId (assuming u would have given a unique ID at the time of login to each user) with a list of Strings(each string being URL visited by that user)
- whenever the user hits another URL from Page 1(and only from page1, check it using JS), send a POST request to backend with the new URL in its data section.
- In the backend, check if the URL is of Page 10 and if not, add this URL as a string into the MAP for that corresponding user
- Finally, when the user clicks on the Page 10 URL, you know the URLs in the way from Page 1 to Page 10 and so use them.

Answer (score 0):

Though if I consider JS and I have not misunderstood your question, we can get the previous URL from request header information using `document.referrer`.

Are you trying to do it from 'Google Tag Manager'? I am not sure whether you are trying to trace the URLS in clientside or server side?